# What is the correct way to create a object array in java?

Tags: java, syntax

I've seen examples such as:

```
Type arrayname[] = new Type[];
```

also as written as:

```
Type[] arrayname = new Type[]
```

I am quite confused about such expressions!

Where exactly should I put the `[]`?

Comment: Both are legal.  Personally I prefer putting it on the `Type` as it is type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the above are allowed. All produce the same bytecode. [JLS-10.2 Array Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) says (in part)

> The `[]` may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

Comment: So no difference for the arrays comprising Objects or the primitive types?

Comment: @tonyabracadabra No. But, all arrays in Java are `Object`s.